# Flatten a Dataframe that is pivoted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code that is taking a single column and pivoting it into multiple columns. There are blanks in my result that I am trying to remove but I am running into issues with the wrong values being applied to rows.

```
task_df = task_df.pivot(index=pivot_cols, columns='Field')['Value'].reset_index()
task_df[['Color','Class']] = task_df[['Color','Class']].bfill()
task_df[['Color','Class']] = task_df[['Color','Class']].ffill()
task_df = task_df.drop_duplicates()
```

Start

[image: Start]

Current

[image: Current]

Desired

[image: Desired]

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, post the text itself. For preformatted text, use [code formatting](/editing-help#code) with the `none` grammar.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically merging all rows having the same name or id together. You can do it with this:

```
mergers = {'ID': 'first', 'Color': 'sum', 'Class': 'sum'}
task_df = task_df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).aggregate(mergers).reindex(columns=task_df.columns).sort_values(by=['ID'])
```